# Incorrect form method generated by form helper

Tags: php, cakephp

My problem is based in the code below:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(
  'Page', array(
    'url' => array(
      'controller' => 'pages',
      'action' => 'delete',
      $this->request->data['Page']['id'],
      'admin' => true
    ),
    'id' => 'PageDeleteForm',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'class' => 'hide'
  )
); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

The result generated by CakePHP is:

```
<form action="/admin/pages/delete/16" id="PageDeleteForm" method="post" class="hide" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    </div>
</form>
```

Because that my delete method returns: **Method not allowed**, and the register is not deleted.

## The problem, the mistery

So the problem is: for default, CakePHP create a form with **method => POST**, and set the input with POST too. But in my case, it's set **PUT**. Why that?

**Action:**

```
/**
 * admin_delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
  public function admin_delete($id = null) {
    $this->Page->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Page->exists()) {
      throw new NotFoundException(__('Página inválida'));
    }

    $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');

    $page = $this->Page->getById($id);
```

Why CakePHP override my instruction (`'method' => 'POST'`) and change for PUT?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
'methdo' => 'POST',
```

Also if you delete something you want to use 'DELETE'.

I'm not sure why Cake by default is using put here for you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I test now, with `'method' => 'POST'`. and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed first problem!**

```
'type' => 'POST'
```

Instead `'method' => 'POST'`.

---

**Second problem:** if I remove the `'type' => 'POST'`, the input keep value PUT.

---

So, the problem is solved for now, the I continue not understand why CakePHP set PUT in input.